# As tags [front-end] e [client-side] deveriam ser sinônimas?

Tags: debate, tags-sinônimas

Assim como os termos back-end e server-side, a tag [front-end](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/front-end)

> parte do sistema de software que interage diretamente com o usuário

e a [client-side](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/client-side) (e sua descrição que merece ser melhor escrita)

> diz respeito à parte de uma aplicação web que roda no navegador do usuário

deveriam ser sinônimas?

Comment: E as aplicações que não são client/server, não podem ter front-end? :P

Comment: Concordo que sim, mas não vejo como usar essa tag nesse contexto que vc citou. E o front-end dessas aplicações não são client-side? :P

Comment: Se não for uma aplicação cliente/servidor, não. Enfim, se concluirmos que são conceitos diferentes, acho melhor manter as duas tags.

Comment: Interagir e rodar é o que define a diferença entre elas. Podemos ter scrips em JavaScript que rodam no cliente, client-side, que não fazem parte do front-end. São coisas conceitualmente distintas.

Comment: Acho que não, mas elas são muito mal usadas.

Comment: Olhando as postagens eu acho é que deveriam ser eliminadas. Numa primeira olhada não achei nenhum caso em que elas contribuissem com o post.

Comment: E se não forem eliminadas, de qq forma não são sinônimas. Exemplo real: tenho um sistema de DB que roda parte server-side e parte client-side. Nenhuma delas faz parte do front-end (nenhuma delas interage com o usuário diretamente, ambas rodam em background). Eventualmente o front-end se conecta com a parte client-side e em algumas ocasiões com a parte server-side. Tudo bem que alguém poderia dizer que o DB local é "server side local", o que eu acho meio forçado, mas isso só contribui para o fato de que as tags não ajudam.

Comment: @Bacco Concordo, remover pode ser uma boa opção.

Comment: Joga no lixo as duas.